# How to get document properties in Office Add-in

Tags: office-365, word, add-ins

I have requirement in which I want to access current editing document Metadata from SharePoint(online) Library using Office Add-in.

I have created word add-In using office js in SharePoint online. I want to get all properties of document(site URL, document library name , file name etc.) I can only get file URL using Office.context.document.url([articel URL](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/reference/shared/document.url.md)). How can I get other properties?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to access the document properties (not the Sharepoint document library metadata) then you can do so via [document.getfilepropertiesasync](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.document?view=office-js). However if you are looking to access the Sharepoint document library metadata then you would have to access the Sharepoint REST API or the Graph API to get the same